# Facebook FQL Location_Post show the author's name

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I use this query:

`SELECT id, author_uid, message, latitude, longitude, timestamp FROM location_post
WHERE author_uid IN
 (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY timestamp DESC";`

My question is how can I show the name from the poster because there is no SELECT name FROM location_post. I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Location_post is: An FQL table that returns Posts that have locations associated with them. What name or name of what are you expecting?

Comment: I want the name of the person who posted the status

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the author_id and make new FQL or graph api request

lets say author_id is 123.

FQL:

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = 123
```

Graph API

```
http://graph.facebook.com/123?fields=name
```

Comment: Thanks you but the output of the author_uid is something like 1.00000127262E+14 and he don't recognize these id's.

Comment: author_uid and all fb ids are out of limit of integer, are you typcasting it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this as a [multiquery](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/#multi):

```
{"locations":"SELECT id, author_uid, message, latitude,...",
 "authors":"SELECT name, id FROM profile WHERE id IN 
            (SELECT author_uid FROM #locations")}
```

Comment: Thanks but when i am going to test this my output is this {
  "data": [
  ]
} 

What do I do wrong? 

{ "locations":"SELECT id, author_uid, message, latitude, longitude, timestamp FROM location_post",
 "authors":"SELECT name, id FROM profile WHERE id IN 
            (SELECT author_id FROM #locations" }


Is it because my author_uid don't get recognized? Because I get this kind of output 1.00000127262E+14

Comment: I had a couple of typos in the original code I posted. These are corrected now. It works in the Graph API Explorer. http://bit.ly/Xe5ClO